Islanders stuck in the 18th c. and ruled by a mysterious 'Q'
TV show form the late 70s or early 80s. 20th century castaways are stranded on an Island. The natives are dressed in 18th c. Fashion (I remember cocked hats quite distinctly) and enslaved (or perhaps just obedient vassals) to a tyrannical (or maybe rather awe-inspiring) 'Q'. The said 'Q' plays chess.

Any idea what country this TV show might have produced this?

I used to watch it when I was a child in Spain, but it is definitely not a Spanish show. It can only haven been British or American.

"Awe-inspiring" person named 'Q', people in out-of-time fashion... anyone else flashing back on Star Trek: The Next Generation?

Sound like The Lost Islands (Australia, 1976)
Some  links:

Wikipedia
IMDB

There also some extracts at Youtube: Ep 1 - "Captured" (there are links to other episodes).

This answer alone justifies the existence of all stackexchange sites! For more than twenty years I have been searching for it. Thank you, thank you, thank you!
